# is it possible to get an 'activity page' (like those in redmine) from JIRA?

Tags: jira, redmine

I'm new to JIRA, and would like to know if there's a similar feature to the 'Project Activity' screen in Redmine.

I find it very useful to be able to see all code changes, updates to issues, wiki page changes, basically anything that is of importance to a project within a nicely timelined page.

an example would be this:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need the [Atlassian Activity Stream Plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/Using+the+Atlassian+Activity+Stream+Plugin). Details for how to get it installed are on [its plugin page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/Atlassian+Activity+Stream+Plugin).

Comment: Peter, thanks for responding to my very first stackoverflow question! i'm sure there will be more to come, hopefully i can contribute back as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Activity Stream comes standard in Jira 4